# New To C and trying to make a collatz conjecture program but it's not working and i don't know why

Tags: c, collatz

This is my attempt at a c program which solves the collatz conjecture i am really new to c and would like to know why my code is not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while ("%d" != 2,num);{
        if (num %2 == 0)
        {
                num = num / 2;
                printf("%d", num);
                count = count + 1;

        }
        else
        {
                num = num * 3 + 1;
                printf("%d", num);
                count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    if (num == 1);
    {
        printf("%d", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `;` here: `while ("%d" != 2,num);{`. Also, what is `"%d" != 2,num` supposed to mean?

Comment: You presumably want `while (num != 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

The condition in while should be a boolean condition, and `num` variable should be different than 1.
I edit also `printfs` to be more suggestive and add a new line to them. I excluded the last `if` condition because it was redundant. When the code finish `while` loop the `num` variable will be 1.

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while (num != 1)
    {
        if (num %2 == 0)
        {
                num = num / 2;
                printf("num = %d\n", num);
                count = count + 1;

        }
        else
        {
                num = num * 3 + 1;
                printf("num = %d\n", num);
                count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("count = %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what part of his code was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I edit the post by adding more information.

Comment: The `count = count + 1;` is not idiomatic C (even though it is what the OP used); normally, you'd use `count++;` or `++count;` (and in C, it really doesn't matter which).  Also, that increment happens in both the `if` and the `else` block, so it could be moved outside both, either before or after the test and print code.

Comment: In C it matters if you do `count++;` or `++count;`. In this particular case won't matter, but in general it's a difference.